# Join table and pick rows where for given id exists only one value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I don't know, if I made good title, but please let me visualize this.

[image]

So I have two tables and for given case I need to select row where payment currency was ONLY in EUR.

Correct document Id's will be: 2, 3, 4, 5

These are overall bigger tables with 900k+ records.

Can you please suggest me how query should look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use correlated subquery with `not exists`

```
select distinct a.document_id from tablename a inner join tablename b b on a.document_id=b.payment_docid
where not exists 
   (select 1 from tablename b1 where b1.payment_docid=b.payment_docid and currency<>'EUR')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this query:

```
select payment_docId from MyTable
group by payment_docId
having max(currency) = 'EUR'
   and min(currency) = 'EUR'
```

or you could use `having count(*) = 1` with `min` or `max` as well.

Answer (score 1):

use corelated subquery

```
select t1.* from table2 as t1
 where exists( select 1 from table2 t2 where t1.payment_docid=t2.payment_docid
                       having count(distinct currency)=1)
and currency='EUR'
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use INNER JOIN with the following conditions to get **all** rows:

```
SELECT
  pd.payment_doc_id
, pd.currency
FROM DocTable dt 
INNER JOIN PaymentDocs pd 
    ON dt.document_id = pd.payment_doc_id AND pd.currency IN ('EUR')
```

If you want **distinct** rows, then you can apply operator `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
  pd.payment_doc_id
, pd.currency
FROM DocTable dt 
INNER JOIN PaymentDocs pd 
    ON dt.document_id = pd.payment_doc_id AND pd.currency IN ('EUR')
GROUP BY   pd.payment_doc_id
         , pd.currency
```

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation is the only efficient want :

```
select doc_id
from table t
group by doc_id
having min(currency) = max(currency) and min(currency) = 'EUR';
```